# Is sharding necessary for subcollections in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have read in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/shard-timestamp?hl=en), that writes per second can be limited to 500 per second if a collection has sequential values with an index.

I am saving sequential timestamps in a subcollection.

**I would like to know if I need a shard field in this specific case to increase the maximum writes per second?**

I am only using "normal" collection indexes, no collection group index.

Some additional explanations:

I have a top level collection called "companies" and under every document is a subcollection called "orders". Every order document has a timestamp "created". This field is indexed and I need this index. These orders could be created very frequently. I am sure that the 500 writes per second limit would apply to this constellation. But I wonder if every subcollection "orders" would have its own limit of 500 writes per second or if all subcollections share one limit. I could add a shard field to avoid the write limit as stated in the documentation but if every subcollection would get its own limit this would not be necessary for my specific case. 500 write per second per subcollection should be more than enough. I think that every subcollection has its own index as long as I am not using a collection group index. And therefore the server should be able to split the data across multiple servers if necessary. But maybe I am wrong. I can't find any concrete informations on that in the documentation or in the internet.

Screenshots from database:

[root collection companies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7qMt.png)

[subcollection orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDdvA.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "sequential timestamps"? Can you show us an example?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added some more informations. I hope that it is now more clear what I want to know. I would be really glad if you could bring same insights here.

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added two Screenshots from the firebase console. Hope that helps.